# Iterate a Dynamically Allocated Array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I need to dynamically allocate an array of type `int` with size 12MB. I did it as follows:

```
unsigned int *memory;
memory = (int *) malloc( 3072 * sizeof(int));
```

How would I iterate through the array without having to use `3072`? Is there a way to get the length of the array? Or should I just do `for (int i = 0; i < 3072; i++)`?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof( a pointer pointing to an array )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The is no portable or convenient way to find out how large the allocate chunk is. After `malloc` is done all that is visible is a pointer to an indeterminate amount of memory (*). You must do the bookkeeping yourself.

---

<sub>(*) Actually `malloc` and friends *do* know how large the chunk is but there is no standard way for a client to access this information.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Pointers in C have no inherent length hence there is no way to do this.  You must keep the length paired with the pointer throughout it's lifetime.

Comment: The length of an array can be calculated as `sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)`, a *pointer*, though is different.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way. You should put 3072 in a const int, which would make the code better and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

With MSVC and MinGW you can use the nonportable _msize function, like

```
char *c=malloc(1234);
printf("%lu",(unsigned long)_msize(c));
free(c);
```